# Installing Ubuntu: Partitioned hard-drive while installing, does not show up in boot order

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, windows-10

I tried installing Ubuntu, and since my laptop manufacturer does not allow me to turn off Secure Boot, I have to alter the boot order so I can access the Ubuntu partition. Only thing is it does not show up in the boot order, only the following appear:

- Windows Boot Manager
- HDD0: SAMSUNG MZNLN...
- HDD1: WDC WD10JP...
- ATAPI CDROM: HL-DT...
- USB FDD
- Network Boot - IPV4
- USB HDD
- USB CDROM
- Network Boot -IPV6

I tried putting HDD0 first, still booted windows. I put it back and put HDD1 first and didn't change a thing. I go to Windows Disk Management and it still shows my partition.

I tried running ubuntu off a flash drive and installed Boot Repair. When I did so and restarted my system it gave me a GRUB screen with what looked like a terminal or bash - like format. I didn't exactly know what to do with that, but every time after I restart my computer it just goes straight to windows.

I need a Linux system so I can run Tensor Flow, if I can do this off a flash drive, I'm fine with that. Just need some help getting everything set up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, use EasyBCD to add Ubuntu partition. Second, is the "GRUB screen with what looked like a terminal or bash" says "grub rescue"?

Comment: Make UEFI install, Ubuntu and other major Linuxes have supported UEFI for some time now, for this reason, as well as for GPT support and other new hardware!

Comment: @DMaster:

1: Should I add the EasyBCD partition, even though I have already partitioned the hard drive. Wouldn't this just create an additional partition?

2: From what I can remember, it wasn't a rescue thing, going off of past Google Searches I think it said "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions." Or something like that

Comment: I am not a fan of EasyBCD. It does not work with new UEFI systems, and forces you to install grub2 to partition which grub2 does not recommend as it is unreliable. If you have multiple drives, just install grub to MBR of other drive. If Windows 10 make sure fast startup is off. May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @KenM (first are you the notorious KenM?) also I don't follow, UEFI is already installed, Ubuntu is, theoretically, still installed, could you clarify or send me a link to show how to do it?

Comment: @oldfred I'm running Windows 10 and fast startup is off. grub2 (which should give me a menu right?) isn't working. I can't install BootInfo summary right now because I need an Ethernet port (Ubuntu WiFi isn't working right now), I will send the summary report later this evening. Thanks

Comment: Then It should work with secure boot, Ubuntu (Canonical) have added the nesesery credentials to the key-server, no need to do special boot to install!

Comment: @SeanKessel "Should I add the EasyBCD ..." No, I didn't said that. I said add Ubuntu partition to EasyBCD list

Comment: "2: From what I can ... Minial BASH-like ..." I wonder is that DOS interface or Linux command-line interface. Could you try ctrl-alt-f1 to see wether there's a enter login prompt?

Comment: @SeanKessel See this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/SecureBoot

Comment: @DMaster, right now installing EasyBCD, it came up with an error message saying "EasyBCD has detected that your machine is currently booting in EFI mode. Due to limitations set by Microsoft, many of EasyBCD’s multi-booting features cannot be used in EFI mode and have been disabled." I went [here](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/uefi/) and it says "This means that you can no longer use EasyBCD to add Windows 9x, XP, or Server 2003 entries to the BCD bootloader menu. You also cannot add DOS, Linux, BSD, or Mac entries."

Comment: @SeanKessel Crap! I guess you can't even disable UEFI.

Comment: @DMaster, I can't get the screen back up without connecting to an ethernet cable (I need to reinstall the Boot Repair to get there, restart, only then does it show) I can do that later tonight

Comment: Does anyone know if I can install and run Tensor Flow off a USB, thats all I need linux for right now

Comment: @Sean No why?
Whar disk is your Windows on!  Install Ubuntu and Grub2 on the other and use the One time boot option( usually F12) and chose the other disk.